# "soap header security was not understood" wse3 vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, soap, wsdl, wse3.0

I am trying to get the response from a web service which i have no control over, i just have the wsdl that is it. its an old wse3 webservice 10+ more years.

I am using vs2012 to consume the wse3 web service. i added it to vs2012 by adding a web reference. so i could use microsoft.web.services3.webservicesclientprotocol

The web service as wsse:security, to make the request i used the UsernameToken class but now the web service response is giving me the error "soap header security was not understood".

I used fiddler to confirme that i has getting an response and i am (note: to see the xml in fidler i had click "Response is encoded and may require decoding before inspection" ), the response also as an wsse:security. header with "soapenv:mustUnderstand =1".

what can i do to get the webservice response?

thank in advance

ps: googling gave a couple of anseres but nothing worked

Comment: Have you tried using SoapUI to see if there is anything coming back?

Comment: yup, that was my frist move make the web service work in soapui.

Comment: wse3 specifies the security policy using an additional config file. Can you ask the administrator of the web service you are consuming to give you a copy of the policy file? It will most likely be in the top level folder for the service on the IIS server and might  be named something like wse3policyCache.config. The policy file will give you clues about how to set up ws-security on the client side.

Comment: i don't have access to the web service code. it's a very old webservice 2001. like i said in the post i used UsernameToken to make the request,  is there no method that does the same for de response?